# How can we get GroovyfirstRowResult to just list values, and not the column headers and without flower braces when shown in .gsp view?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, grails-controller, grails-services

In the groovy Controller Code I call the function:

```
def wiki =   
{  
    def currentNode = params.nodePath  
    def conceptName = nodeService.retrieveConceptName (currentNode);  
    render (template:'wiki', model:[conceptName : conceptName])
}
```

In the service class I define the function retrieveConceptName:

```
def retrieveConceptName(currentNode)  
{  
    groovy.sql.Sql sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource);  
    def row= sql.firstRow(" SELECT cname FROM Person WHERE FULLNAME= ?",[currentNode]);  
    return row;  
}
```

In my output(wiki template(gsp view)) I get flowerbrackets along with field header , How to get only value of column and not the flower braces or field header?

Comment: "flowerbrackets" - this could really catch on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown the GSP code that displays the row, but I guess it looks like either `${it}` or `${row}`. If so, replace it with either

`${it.cname}` or `${row.cname}`

Comment: In the service class in my SQL statement above sometimes returns numbers with concepts for ex: 01 John, 02 Smith. How can I filter only John, Smith values and not the numbers. I want to show in my gsp view only John , Smith and not the number tags before them?

Comment: @sp123 please post this as a new question